# How to perform element wise addition to a particular row in Octave?

Tags: matrix, octave, matrix-multiplication

I've a two matrices

`A = [0 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0]`
and

`B = [2 3 4;]`

How will I get

`A = [0 0 0; 2 3 4; 0 0 0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Octave you could set/update any part of the original matrix.

For example, here is how to add vector `B` to the second row of a matrix `A`:

```
A(2,:) = A(2,:) + B;
```

Comment: you could also use the simplest `A(2,:) += B;`